# Second partial derivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Problem:** Verify that $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t\int_{x-ct+cs}^{x+ct-cs}f(y,s)\,dy\,ds$ is a solution to $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=f$ with BC $u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$.

**Attempt:** First find $u_{tt}$

$$\begin{split}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t\int_{x-ct+cs}^{x+ct-cs}f(y,s)\,dy\,ds&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac12\left(\int_x^xf(y,t)\,dy-\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}f(y,0)\,dy\right)\\ &=-\frac12\left(\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\partial_tf(y,0)\,dy+cf(x+ct,0)-cf(x-ct,0)\right)\\ &=\frac c2f(x-ct,0)-\frac c2f(x+ct,0)\end{split}$$

Now find $c^2u_{xx}$

$$\begin{split}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac{c}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-ct+cs}^{x+ct-cs}f(y,s)\,dy\,ds&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac c2\int_0^t\partial_x\left(\int_{x-ct+cs}^{x+ct-cs}f(y,s)\,dy\right)\,ds\\ &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac c2\int_0^tf(x+ct-cs,s)-f(x-ct+cs,s)\,ds\\ &=\frac c2\int_0^t\partial_xf(x+ct-cs,s)-\partial_xf(x-ct+cs,s)\,ds\\ &=\,???\end{split}$$

Now I'm stuck.